# corpus extraction with changing data type R

Tags: data-extraction

i have a corpus of text files, contains just text, I want to extract the ngrams from the texts and save each one with his original file name in matrixes of 3 columns..

```
   library(tokenizer)      
    myTokenizer <- function(x, n, n_min) {

corp<-"this is a full text "
     tok <- unlist(tokenize_ngrams(as.character(x), n = n, n_min = n_min))
      M <- matrix(nrow=length(tok), ncol=3, 
                  dimnames=list(NULL, c( "gram" , "num.words", "words")))
      }
    corp <- tm_map(corp,content_transformer(function (x) myTokenizer(x, n=3, n_min=1)))

        writecorpus(corp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to create a document term matrix (DTM). You will probably need this in your downstream tasks anyway. From that you could also extract the information you want, although, it is probably not reasonable to assume that a term (incl. ngrams) only has a single document where its coming from (at least this is what I understood from your question, please correct me if I am wrong). Therefore, I guess that in practice one term will have several documents associated with it - this kind of information is usually stored in a DTM.

An example with `text2vec` below. If you could elaborate further how you want to use your terms, etc. I could adapt the code according to your needs.

```
library(text2vec)
# I have set up two text do not overlap in any term just as an example
# in practice, this probably never happens
docs = c(d1 = c("here a text"), d2 = c("and another one"))
it = itoken(docs, tokenizer = word_tokenizer, progressbar = F)
v = create_vocabulary(it, ngram = c(1,3))
vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(v)
dtm = create_dtm(it, vectorizer)
as.matrix(dtm)
#    a a_text and and_another and_another_one another another_one here here_a here_a_text one text
# d1 1      1   0           0               0       0           0    1      1           1   0    1
# d2 0      0   1           1               1       1           1    0      0           0   1    0

library(stringi)
docs = c(d1 = c("here a text"), d2 = c("and another one"))
it = itoken(docs, tokenizer = word_tokenizer, progressbar = F)
v = create_vocabulary(it, ngram = c(1,3))
vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(v)
dtm = create_dtm(it, vectorizer)
for (d in rownames(dtm)) {
  v = dtm[d, ]
  v = v[v!=0]
  v = data.frame(number = 1:length(v)
                 ,term = names(v))
  v$n = stri_count_fixed(v$term, "_")+1
  write.csv(v, file = paste0("v_", d, ".csv"), row.names = F)
}
read.csv("v_d1.csv")
#   number        term n
# 1      1           a 1
# 2      2      a_text 2
# 3      3        here 1
# 4      4      here_a 2
# 5      5 here_a_text 3
# 6      6        text 1
read.csv("v_d2.csv")
#   number            term n
# 1      1             and 1
# 2      2     and_another 2
# 3      3 and_another_one 3
# 4      4         another 1
# 5      5     another_one 2
# 6      6             one 1
```

Comment: another update, you will now get as many files as you have documents... you will need an additional loop to read each document, of course wrapped around the loop proposed so far or load all your documents into a list and loop over this list for creating the vocabulary.

Comment: i upvoted it and accept it but i have no repudations they told me that my upvote will not be considered :(

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have your corpus I created one of my own using the crude dataset from tm. No need to use tm_map as that keeps the data in a corpus format. The tokenizer package can handle this.

What I do is store all your desired matrices in a list object via `lapply` and then use `sapply` to store the data in the crude directory as separate files.

Do realize that the matrices as specified in your function will be character matrices. This means that columns 1 and 2 will be characters, not numbers.

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)

myTokenizer <- function(x, n, n_min) {
  tok <- unlist(tokenizers::tokenize_ngrams(as.character(x), n = n, n_min = n_min))
  M <- matrix(nrow=length(tok), ncol=3, 
              dimnames=list(NULL, c( "gram" , "num.words", "words")))
  M[, 3] <- tok
  M[, 2] <- lengths(strsplit(M[, 3], "\\W+"))  # counts the words
  M[, 1] <- 1:length(tok)
  return(M)
}

my_matrices <- lapply(crude, myTokenizer, n = 3, n_min = 1)

#  make sure directory crude exists as a subfolder in working directory
sapply(names(my_matrices), 
       function (x) write.table(my_matrices[[x]], file=paste("crude/", x, ".txt", sep=""), row.names = FALSE))
```

outcome of the first file:

```
"gram" "num.words" "words"
"1" "1" "diamond"
"2" "2" "diamond shamrock"
"3" "3" "diamond shamrock corp"
"4" "1" "shamrock"
"5" "2" "shamrock corp"
"6" "3" "shamrock corp said"
```